# Webview error load javascript in android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm having a problem later

Webview worked in Android above 5.0. But Android below 5.0. It Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier From line 46 at https:/"example"/rader/app.js
```

this is code in **app.js**

```
function viewData() {
getData().done(function(data){
radar_json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log('---radar_json---');
console.log(radar_json);

// arrayæ•´å½¢
temp_time_arr = [];
for(let ra of radar_json.radar) {   // This is line 46
  if(ra) {
    ra.dataList.forEach(function(item, index){
      //time = time.replace(/-/g, '/');
      temp_time_arr.push(new Date(item.datatime).getTime());
    })
  }
}
```

any idea? Can you help me!

Comment: `let...of` probably not supported in older browser of 4.4 ... have you considered transpiling your code?

Comment: Can you guide me a way of transcoding it?

Comment: no, I can't help transcoding it as I suggested transpiling it, and as I'm not even familiar with webview, it may well be the wrong thing to do ... try writing your code for a "dumber" browser ... check caniuse.com for support of newer syntax etc ...

Comment: I will try it!! thanks you!